# Is armor's DR additive and covering whole body?

Tags: fallout-4

I must be missing something obvious here, but the costumes seem to provide MUCH better DR than even the best armors: The [Silver Shroud costume](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Silver_Shroud_costume) initially gives 42 DR (both normal and energy) while i.e. [Combat armor](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Combat_armor_(Fallout_4)) chest piece only 15 and CA leg  - 8 DR.

If the total damage resistance from mix-and-match armor is the sum of all its parts and it doesn't matter where you are hit (leg with 2 DR or chest with 20) then those are comparable  - full, unmodified (and much more expensive) combat armor would give 59 DR, but if only the DR of hit body part is taken into consideration, then costumes are hands down better option.

So, which one is it? Is the DR of mix-and-match armor the sum of DR of its parts ? If no, whats even the point of taking such armors over costumes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Damage resistance is additive across all armour pieces, instead of applying to each body part individually. The reason for choosing a costume over individual pieces is that it can often look better than the mish-mash of different types of armour.

Comment: As evidence of this: As you switch your apparel, note the DR display in the lower right-hand corner of the pip-boy. You can see it go up when you equip a piece of limb armor, and drop when you replace all your armor with a costume.

Comment: @DCShannon, some limb armor mods have Strengthened mod with 'reduces limb damage' effect. How does that work? I'd suppose that limb ignores some damage if DR is global, but that's just speculation.

Comment: @icebat That's a great question. You should ask it.