# What does Strengthened armor mode do (limb damage)?

Tags: fallout-4

As was discussed in question [Is armor's DR additive and covering whole body?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/244061/62507), the armor rating seems to be total, not for each body part separately.

Supposing that's correct, what exactly does 'reduces limb damage' effect in Strengthened armor mod do? Reduce incoming damage to a limb for some percentage? Is a piece with this mod better than a piece with a higher armor rating but without such mod?

Comment: I would imagine it reduces the chance of a limb becoming crippled when taking damage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Limbs have their own health bars, independent of player health. When these are depleted (by taking direct hits to the limb in question), you'll be crippled (Indicated by a wounded pip boy icon popping up in the top right of the screen momentarily).

[image: Pip Boy Screenshot]
(Note the individual health bars next to each arm and leg, as well as the head).

When one of your legs is crippled, for example, you'll find your movement speed severely reduced.

Using a stimpack will heal any crippled limbs, in addition to healing player health.

The Strengthened Armor mod, and other effects that increase or reduce 'limb damage' serve to prevent you from being crippled as easily.

Comment: I think one of the most important aspects of the question is whether the limb damage reduction is global, like the armor's DR, or if it only applies to the limb with the mod.

Comment: @DCShannon I'd be *shocked* if it wasn't just a global reduction, though I haven't been able to test it.

Comment: I would not be surprised either way.

Comment: Too bad there's no co-op, it would be easy to test. I'm not sure how you can easily verify this in game. Maybe with explosives, but that's messy.

Comment: @icebat If you have a PC and can do stuff with the console, you could try putting strengthened armor on an NPC and shooting the limb it's on with and without it, and then another limb with and without it on the first limb. You can see limb health bars in VATS.

Comment: The limb damage reduction is global. I tested by simply firing explosive shotgun on the ground, which only damage the legs HP. Followed by wearing *Strengthen* mod on the head gear, it took more shot to cripple my legs.